# MVC 6 Seeding users in a loop always fails on the 14th user with cannot access disposed object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to seed a variable amount of users depending on current needs.  This worked fine in MVC4 without async.  Now that MVC6 requires Async I keep getting failures when trying to seed more than 13 users.  I am using the standard RC1 final AccountController template:

```
        [FromServices]
        public DecAppContext DecAppContext { get; set; }

        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
        private readonly ISmsSender _smsSender;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;
        private static bool _databaseChecked;

        public AccountController(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            ISmsSender smsSender,
            ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _smsSender = smsSender;
            _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
        } ...
```

I am trying to register 300 users here:

```
BatchRegister(300);
public async void BatchRegister(int users = 0, int n = 1)
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();
            while (n <= users)
            {
                string password = "T3sT*" + rnd.Next(1, 99).ToString();
                string usernm = "Test" + n.ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine("Going to register user" + usernm);
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = usernm, Email = usernm + "@noemail.com" };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Registered User " + usernm + " " + password);
                }
                n++;
            }
    }
```

The above runs just fine for the first 13 users.  They are in the DB and I can login with the accounts.  However, if I enter in more than 13 users the program crashes on  var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password) with the error:

> "Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'UserStore`3'."

Any help in understanding why this is happening and a solution would be much appreciated.  It isn't feasible for me to enter these line by line.  For some tests I need to enter in 2000 users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  Since I was calling batch register in another method without the await keyword it seems once the view was rendered it stopped working.  I have changed the call to:

```
await BatchRegister(300);
```

I thought the await in the BatchRegister method would prevent the call to the view from proceeding until the BatchRegister method was done.  But apparently it doesn't.  You have to tell the calling method to await so it waits until it is done.  I am apparently still missing some concepts for asynchronous programming.  I thought the purpose of await was to make it so the views would not be held up waiting for something in the background.  Guess I will go back to researching that thought further.